# What would happen if I were to drop this CREDENTIAL in my Azure DB

Tags: sql, database, azure

My main goal is to get Cross-Database queries working between two Azure Databases. In order to do so, I've come across Elastic Queries. The examples I've seen on how to get started with Elastic Queries show people creating a Master Key with encryption by password like so:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<password>';
GO 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ElasticDBCredential WITH IDENTITY = 'ElasticUser', SECRET = '<password>';
GO
```

Although my Database already has a Master Key, and I get this message when I try and drop the Master Key

> Cannot drop master key because CREDENTIAL
> 'https://****.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs' is
> encrypted by it.

I have Audit Logs turned on for this DB and it is encrypted by the existing Master Key, apparently. I tried dropping the Credential doing this:

```
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [https://****.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs]
```

But this also returns the error:

> Cannot drop the credential 'https://****.windows.net/sqldbauditlogs' because it is being used.

How would I make it so it's "not in use" so that I can drop it OR I could use the existing Master Key, I just don't know how to figure out what it is currently...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first ALTER the master key and regenerate it using the new password as follow:

```
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'NewPassword';
```

Any CREDENTIAL using old master key will automatically inherit the new master key since there can only be one master key.

Now, drop  the DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY and then drop the CERTIFICATE and last drop the MASTER KEY.

The following example removes the database encryption and drops the database encryption key.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
SET ENCRYPTION OFF;  
GO  
/* Wait for decryption operation to complete, look for a   
value of  1 in the query below. */  
SELECT encryption_state  
FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys;  
GO  
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DROP DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY;  
GO
```

Drop the credentials.

```
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credential_name
```

Answer (score 0):

- Drop external Table [EXTERNAL TABLE Name]
- Drop external data source [Data Source Name]
- Drop DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [Name]
- Drop Master key